# C#: Extract number out of string, then change comma(,) to dot(.)

Tags: c#, regex, internationalization, number-formatting, decimal-point

I'm using Visual Web Ripper to extract name and prices on products on a website.

When i extract the price from a table it comes in a form like this:

> Kr. 129,30

I need to extract the 129,30, then turn the comma to a dot (129.30).

Visual Web Ripper can use scripts to modify the extracted content. It can use standard Regex, C# and VB.NET.

In the Regex tab I have found that

```
(\d+.)?(\d+)(.\d+)?
```

gives me 129,30, but then I can't change the comma into a dot.

Therefor I have to use C#. It comes with this standard script:

```
using System;
using VisualWebRipper.Internal.SimpleHtmlParser;
using VisualWebRipper;
public class Script
{
    //See help for a definition of WrContentTransformationArguments.
    public static string TransformContent(WrContentTransformationArguments args)
    {
        try
        {
            //Place your transformation code here.
            //This example just returns the input data
            return args.Content;
        }
        catch(Exception exp)
        {
            //Place error handling here
            args.WriteDebug("Custom script error: " + exp.Message);
            return "Custom script error";
        }
    }
}
```

How do I modify it to extract the number then replace the comma with a dot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is obviously [Krona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedish_krona), so we should use the Swedish culture info to translate it. First we start with the input:

```
var original = "Kr. 129,30";
```

Get the culture:

```
using System.Globalization;
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE");
```

This culture expects the currency string to be `kr` (case insensitive) but we have `Kr.`. So let's update it:

```
var format = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.NumberFormat.Clone();    
format.CurrencySymbol = "Kr.";
```

And now the culture aware parse:

```
var number = Decimal.Parse(original, NumberStyles.Currency, format);
```

Now `number` contains a decimal that has been parsed correctly.

Comment: Thank you! :) Using `return number.ToString();` I get "129,30". Now how do i get "129.30"? :)

Comment: It's not obviously *Swedish* kroner, is it?  Why not Norwegian or Danish culture?

Comment: @galskab `number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` but really the answer depends a bit on *why* you want to get a string with a dot decimal separator.

Comment: @phoog correct, but this is an example - I wouldn't hard code Sweden! He's getting this off a shopping website - I'd use the country of that website. And also your comment on why you want to turn it into a string with '.' is spot on.

Comment: @phoog True :) It's actually Norwegian, but that doesn't matter :) Thanks, `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` works! :)

Answer (score 4):

String.Replace is an option ( `text.Replace(",", ".")`).

It would be better to properly parse number with correct CultureInfo and than reformat it back with InvariantCulture.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I do that? :) **I started looking at C# for the first time today.**

Can I apply culture info to the string(Kr. 129,30) and get 129.30? Or do I have to extract the number first? I can't figure out how to use Regex the same way in C# as in just Regex.